# Lightbox popup loading slowly in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lightbox

I am using the lightbox plugin to show popups in my app.
Some popup's consist of multiple images.
So when a popup loads it shows images one by one.
My question is how can i load all images and show them at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help if you were a bit more specific as to what javascript framework you're using, exactly what plugin you're using (a link to it, for example), etc etc.

To answer your question, if you loading a lot of images, yes that's going to be slow.  You can try spriting them into one image or you can change your view so that you're only loading one image at a time.

You could also designate a single server for serving assets and store your images there.  That could speed things up some.